# Delete sub-directories in array that do not contain a specific file

Tags: php

This is probably just my inexperience and there's got to be a way, but it seems everything I'm trying leads me to one road block: I can't get php to 'act' on the sub-directories that don't have the specific file (index.php).

In the following code, it just sees it as true or false, so the result will be the 'else' giving me a list of the 'good folders (with index)+the message, or if I removed the (!), it would delete the good folders. I need it to give me the results of the bad folders (without index) so we can destroy them! haha (the deleteDirectory is a function to allow deletion of non-empty folders). Thank you!
edit: btw, if it is not possible this way, i'm open to work arounds..I've tried to 'rename' the good directories temporarily for the purge which I was having problems with the array, and also to create a 'dummy file' in non index directories, but the end result is the same as far as there being a point it has to differentiate.

```
$path = glob(DIR_DIR  . '*' . '/index.php');
foreach ($path as $path) {
    if (!is_file($path)) {
        $path = str_replace('/index.php', '', $path);
        deleteDirectory($path); 
    } else { 
        echo $path . '...all folders contain index.php...<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: You are echoing the “all folders” message _inside_ your loop – that’s nonsense of course, because at that point you have not even _looked_ at all folders. Use a flag instead inside your loop – set `$allFoldersContainIndex` to `true`before your loop, change it to `false` _inside_ the loop if you encounter a folder that does not contain an `index.php` – and then check the value of that flag _after_ your loop.

Comment: And `foreach ($path as $path)` is nonsense as well, because you are overwriting your array variable here with the first value on the first loop iteration already – chose a _different_ name for the second variable here.

Comment: Hi CBroe. I read up more on how the foreach works and understand that now. But I'm not getting you on the set flag part. I'm doing $allFoldersContainIndex=true; before the foreach and false after the foreach, echoing it after the loop's }. But the value only returns as "1" which I think is just the last result of an array? Does $allFoldersContainIndex have to be set to anything besides true, pre-loop to define what it is? And thank you, too.

Comment: I didn’t say you should _set_ it to false _after_ the loop – you should _check_ its value after. And `1` is what you get when you output a `true` value via `echo` – get used to using `var_dump` for stuff like that, it’ll tell you the _real_ value and type of a variable.